# Library to convert JSON string to Erlang record

Tags: json, erlang, record

I've a large JSON string, I want to convert this string into Erlang record.
I found [jiffy](https://github.com/davisp/jiffy) library but it doesn't completely convert to record.

For example:
`jiffy:decode(<<"{\"foo\":\"bar\"}">>).`
gives

`{[{<<"foo">>,<<"bar">>}]}`

but I want the following output:

`{ok,{obj,[{"foo",<<"bar">>}]},[]}`

Is there any library that can be used for the desired output?

Or is there any library that can be used in combination of [jiffy](https://github.com/davisp/jiffy) for further modifying the output of it.

Consider the fact the JSON string is large, and I want the output is minimum time.

Comment: Very strange question. Why the decode function should add this `{obj,List}` tuple, why `\"foo\"` and `\"bar\"` should be decoded differently, what is the meaning of the last empty list (I guess it is the remaining part of the input string after the first term has been decoded)? It looks like that what you are expecting is very specific, and that there is some context missing in your question. I encourage you to look how you can use the library output, and eventually explain what are the missing features.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [ejson](https://github.com/jonasrichard/ejson), from the documentation:

> JSON library for Erlang on top of jsx. It gives a declarative interface for jsx by which we need to specify conversion rules and ejson will convert tuples according to the rules.
>
> I made this library to make easy not just the encoding but rather the decoding of JSONs to Erlang records...
>
> In order for ejson to take effect the source files need to be compiled with parse_transform ejson_trans. All record which has -json attribute can be converted to JSON later.